# Issue while using yasca in CentOS

Tags: static-analysis

Is yaska supported in Linux? I tried installing it on CentOS and getting below error.

[root@390f68c98d2b yasca]# sh yasca.sh ./resources/test

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Class Yasca\Scanner could not be loaded' in /var/www/html/yasca/Yasca/Main.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/yasca/Yasca/Main.php(36): spl_autoload('Yasca\\Scanner')
#1 [internal function]: {closure}()
#2 /var/www/html/yasca/Yasca/Main.php(357): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#3 /var/www/html/yasca/Yasca/Start.php(14): include('/var/www/html/y...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/yasca/Yasca/Main.php on line 36
```

[image]

Can someone please help in this?

Comment: Please don't post images, post the actual text.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Updated.